# Fundraise From Something

Tags: meaning-in-context, ellipsis

I need some help with some phrase:

> [link](http://news.yahoo.com/congresswoman-who-co-sponsored-impeachment-bill-of-bush-said-democrats-never-tried-to-impeach-bush-142528358.html)
>   Despite Democratic protests on the House floor, however, party lawmakers seem downright gleeful about the exercise after ***fundraising successfully from*** the lawsuit and talk of impeachment.

I cannot find the phrase "*fundraise from something*" in many dictionaries, but it seems similar to "profit from something".  Could it be a error or a journalistic attempt at being cute?

Comment: Its the same as "...after successfully raising funds from the lawsuit and talk of impeachment."

Comment: @user3169 Is the original poorly written?

Comment: To me it is confusing. I think if you change "fundraising successfully *from* the lawsuit and talk of impeachment." to "fundraising successfully *due to* the lawsuit and talk of impeachment." it might make better sense.

Answer (score 1):

It just means the lawsuit and talk of impeachment *helped them raise funds* (by [fundraising](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundraising), not by adding to their coffers with money from legal damages! :)

Quite *how* "successful" they were is a moot point. They might have made a *lot* of money, or they might be "gleeful" to have raised *any* amount of money at all in the circumstances (I have no idea).

---

You can understand ***from*** as ***using***. An alternative, particularly in more informal registers, is...

> *...after fundraising successfully **on** (or **off**) **the back of** the lawsuit*

Comment: Is the original not well-written?

Comment: @meatie: I suppose it's not well-written from your point of view, if you couldn't understand it. What I don't understand is what you find so difficult about those particular three words, given you've obviously read several far more complex sentences earlier in the piece. I can't believe you don't understand *fundraising*, so I'm forced to suppose you simply got stuck because of the specific preposition ***from***. But the relationship itself is obvious, *whatever* preposition is used. So I still don't understand your problem.

Comment: It is indeed the preposition "*from*" that is the problem.  The original does read like money from a lawsuit settlement is used for political campaigning.

Comment: @meatie, I think it was poorly written. It wasn't clear to me at all what they meant until I read FumbleFingers' explanation.

Comment: @Dangph, meatie: I'm surprised that a native speaker should have difficulty with the phrasing. For the record, I definitely do *not* think there's anything wrong with it in any "objective" sense. If you check the context, it's obviously from a competent writer who's not afraid to use long and complex syntax. There's no "standard" preposition for use in the precise context, but ***from*** is imho the best of a bad bunch unless he wanted to adopt a more informal register (unlikely) and use something like my *on/off the back of*. And it's *not* aimed at non-native speakers, obviously.